# Latest versioning in production code

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I'd like to update my project with the latest version of the Forge Viewer. I haven't previously been using versioning this far. How would I update the Forge Viewer to the latest version in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No versioning, you've been naughty! Take a look at this article:

[Forge Viewer - Always use versioning in production code](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/09/forge-viewer-always-use-versioning-in-production-code.html)

The latest version is [4.0.0](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=4.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to point to the same resources, but omitting the version, thus grabbing the last version.

For example, you would need to include in your html file:

```
<!-- The Viewer CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/style.min.css" type="text/css">
    ...
<!-- The Viewer JS -->
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/three.js"/>
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.js"/>
```

At the same time you might want to be careful. We always advice for use versioning in production code.

Check [this post](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/09/forge-viewer-always-use-versioning-in-production-code.html) from Stephen for more in how and why.